# codename one purchase/product api usage

Tags: in-app-purchase, codenameone

Good day all
I have an app I have been working on of late, and it requires users paying to use the app on a monthly basis

I have looked at the purchase/product api and cant get myself to use it in achieving that

I'll like to get a little help as to how I can achieve this using codename one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See these tutorials on using IAP:

https://www.codenameone.com/blog/intro-to-in-app-purchase.html

https://www.codenameone.com/blog/in-app-purchase-non-renewable-subscriptions.html

https://www.codenameone.com/blog/autorenewing-subscriptions-in-ios-and-android.html

Comment: How do I set the price for the product to be purchased? It wasn't included in the above articles. Thanks

Comment: The price is set in the Apple/play store for managed products.